# Extra padding on PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I'm having some problems with my preferenceactivity. The code show the screen perfect on preview, but when I test on emulator Its show a extra padding on SwitchPreference, and the switch doesn't work.

Besides that, when testing on pre-lollipop emulator, theres no margin at all.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:title="Tema"
        android:key="night_mode"
        android:summary="Ativar tema escuro"/>
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="App Update"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:summary="This option if selected will allow the application to check for latest versions."
        android:key="app_update"/>

    <Preference
        android:title="Clean cache"
        android:summary="Resetar preferencias do app"
        android:key="clean_cache"/>
   <PreferenceScreen
       android:title="Sobre">
       <intent android:targetClass="llamaze.com.br.whattodraw.Activitys.AboutActivity"
           android:targetPackage="llamaze.com.br.whattodraw"/>/

   </PreferenceScreen>/
</PreferenceScreen>

 public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        Context context;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            Preference customPref = findPreference("clean_cache");
            customPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    showDialogCache();
                    Log.d("PREFRE", "onPreferenceClick: foi clicado");

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

Screens:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was resolved by google with the update of preference-v7 to 24.1.1